# Flutter does not recognize my android studio license

Tags: android, flutter

When I type flutter doctor it shows me this:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.9, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.720], locale 
en-US)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
X Android license status unknown.
Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK Manager.
See https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads or visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android- 
setup for detailed
instructions.
[√] Android Studio (version 3.6)
[!] VS Code (version 1.43.1)
X Flutter extension not installed; install from
 https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter
[!] Connected device
! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.
```

I reinstalled android studio but it does not seems to work. What can I do? I am new to flutter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accept the licenses from flutter itself. You can try the following:

1. Open your terminal
2. `flutter doctor --android-licenses`
3. Press `y` to accept all licenses

If this does not work for some reason, you can try the following:

`<exact path to your android sdk>\tools\bin\sdkmanager --licenses`

Comment: If I type flutte doctor --android-licenses this is what my console shows me: Android sdkmanager tool not found (C:\Users\Catal\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\bin\sdkmanager).
Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK,
visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed instructions. If I enter in my own android sdk forlder I find no  folder named tools

Comment: Now it works, aparently I just had to uncheck: Show obsolated packages in Android Studios. Sdk was not even installed due to it being obsolated